# Wso2 EI 7.1.0 request processing

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

1. I want to know about how request processing happens in Wso2 EI 7.1.0, because I am seeing different threads like synapse.threads.core, worker_pool_size_core, snd_t_core, lst_t_core in thread dump.
2. In my use case I created flow which contains API mediator-->Iterate mediator-->Send mediator--->Aggregate--->Respond. So here request will convert as soap to json while sending it to endpoint and response will convert as json to soap while respond it to client, I am using payload factory mediator for request /response format conversion and I observed more time taking for response conversion, So is their any configuration change required as of now I am using default configurations.

Thanks,

Ajay Babu Maguluri.

Answer (score 0):

PassThroughMessageProcessor threads are used to mediate the message through the mediators. By default, this thread pool has 400 threads and you can tune the pool using the worker_pool_size_core, worker_pool_size_max parameters.

But if you are using clone or iterate mediators inside your mediation, SynapseWorker threads are used to handle the targets of those mediators. By default, this thread pool has 20 threads. You can tune the thread pool using synapse.threads.core and synapse.threads.max parameters